# How to use React Native with RubyMotion

Tags: ios, reactjs, rubymotion, react-native

I have built a couple apps in RubyMotion and I would like to take advantage of the many benefits of React Native within those apps? Has anyone been able to get React Native to work inside an existing RubyMotion project?

Answer (score 3):

I have figured this out and I created a repo on Github demonstrating how to integrate a React Native app/component into an existing RubyMotion project: https://github.com/gnestor/rubymotion-react